# Integrating C++ OpenGL project with another C++ project

Tags: c++, opengl, program-entry-point

I was working with a project that reads a data file, performs some calculations, and show results on standard output. Later i wanted to give a 3D graphical view to the results, so I made a new OpenGL project that shows data as 3D object.

Now the problem is, I can not figure out a way to integrate these two independent projects, because the `main()` in my OpenGL project goes in a non terminating `glutMainLoop()` loop, and I am unable to figure out where to put the loop in `main()` of my first project !

```
/**** Proj1 ****/
int main()
{  
    while(ESC key not pressed)
    {
        // read data file
        // do some processing
        // show results on standard output
    }
} 

/**** Proj2 ****/
int main()
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    Init();
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Least mixing of codes between Proj1 & Proj2 is requested.
Is it possible to do something like:

```
/**** Proj1 ****/
#include <filesFromProj2>
int main()
{
    while(ESC key not pressed)
    {
          // read data file
          // do some processing
          proj2.showResult(result)   // how to do this ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution so answering it myself for everyone's reference:

I desperately needed a workaround without having to change my existing glut base code into **GLFW** and **SDF** etc.

Digging more on internet I found that **freeglut** supports a function **glutMainLoopEvent()** that "causes **freeglut** to process one iteration’s worth of events in its event loop. This allows the application to control its own event loop and still use the **freeglut** windowing system."

Also, freeglut supported all the functions of glut (or atleast supported all the glut functions used in my prog). So,i didn't have to change my glut base code.

The pseudo-code for the workaround is as below. I welcome your comments.

```
#include <gl/freeglut.h>
#include <filesFromProj2>
int main()
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    Init();
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);
    // glutMainLoop();       // Do not use this

    while(ESC key not pressed)
    {
        // read data file
        // do some processing
        proj2.showresults(results)
        glutMainLoopEvent();    // One iteration only
        Display();              // Call the func used with glutDisplayFunc()
    }
    glutLeaveMainLoop();
}
```

I also thought that multi-threading, may also solve this problem. One thread for glutMainLoop() and another for data processing !!

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution would be to ditch GLUT and use a OpenGL windowing framework that lets you implement the event loop. GLFW would be the immediate choice. Then instead of having an opaque `glutMainLoop` that never returns you instead call `glfwPollEvents` beside your your stdio processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick answer. I didn't know about GLFW. Most tutorials I read were using GLUT or FreeGLUT. will study about GLFW. It would help more if u could tell when Proj1 is playing a video using OpenCV and Proj2 is the OpenGL object rederning, how can i do both in parallel (where obj redering is dependent on result of img processing of video frame). A sample pseudo code will help more.

Comment: I did it using freeglut's glutMainLoopEvent() function. But thanks for introducing to GLFW. Will use it for my next project.

Answer (score 1):

GLUT decouples your event handling code from your display code. It feels strange if you're used to the paradigm where you have full control over the loop, but it's not really hard to deal with. Basically, you need to maintain a state that your glutDisplayFunc will react to, and update that state in your glutKeyboardFunc. So in pseudocode (it seems like you have the C++ down):

```
displayFunc:
  if state.showProj1
    proj1.showResult
  else if state.showProj2
    proj2.showResult

keyboardFunc
  if keyPressed(esc)
    state.showProj1 = false
    state.showProj2 = true
    glutPostRedisplay()
```

Ok, so that is some pretty naive code there, but it should get the idea of how to make changes to your state in response to user input which in turn affects what you are rendering.

As mentioned in the previous answer, if you want explicit control of the program loop (as opposed to the event-based paradigm), you have some good options in GLFW and SDL, but of course there will be some ramp-up with those since GLUT does things in a pretty different way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick answer. i am not so sure about this method of integration, specially when Proj1 is playing a video using OpenCV and Proj2 is the OpenGL object rederning. How can i do both in parallel (where obj redering is dependent on result of img processing of video frame). The pseudo code u shared, seems like it will call the data processing of proj1 from inside the display func. this dependency is in opposite dir. my requirement is in this seq: Process data (a video frame) -> render 3d obj -> repeat

Comment: Given the complexity of what you're trying to accomplish, I would suggest merging both of your efforts into a GLFW or SDL application. While I have no doubt that it could be accomplished using GLUT, I personally would want the control afforded by writing my own loop. In that way, you could do as you see fit in terms of processing and rendering (even split them into different threads if you wanted). It should be a relatively easy thing to do, since you presumably have all the things written that you need already.

Comment: I did it using freeglut's glutMainLoopEvent() function. But thanks anyways for introducing to GLFW and SDL. Will use it for my next project.